An Implementation of UNIX wc shell utility
The implementation doesn't support the "-m" flag, and only works with ASCII, and has rather terrible output formatting in comparison with GNU's implementation of wc.
Code:
#include <algorithm>
#include <expected>
#include <filesystem>
#include <format>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <system_error>

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <clocale>

#include <getopt.h>
#include <unistd.h>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

struct options {
    bool cflag {false}; /* byte count flag. */
    bool lflag {false}; /* line count flag. */
    bool Lflag {false}; /* max line length flag. */
    bool wflag {false}; /* word count flag. */
};

struct fstats {
    std::uintmax_t lines {0};
    std::uintmax_t words {0};
    std::uintmax_t bytes {0};
    std::uintmax_t max_line_length {0};
};

enum class parse_options_error { 
    help_requested, 
    unknown_option 
};

static auto help(std::ostream& os) -> void {
    os << R"(USAGE
    wc [OPTION]... [FILE]...

NAME
    wc - word, line, and byte count.

DESCRIPTION
    Print line, word, and byte counts for each FILE, and a total line if more
    than one FILE is specified. A line is defined as a string of characters
    delimited by a <newline> character, and a word is defined as a non-zero-
    -length sequence of printable characters delimited by white space. 

    When an option is specified, wc only reports the information requested by
    that option. The default action is equivalent to all the flags -clw having
    been specified.

    When no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

    If more than one input file is specified, a line of cumulative counts for
    all the files is displayed on a separate line after the output for the last
    file.

    By default, the standard output containts a line for each input file of the 
    form:
        lines    words    bytes    file_name

OPTION:
    -c, --bytes                 print the byte counts.
    -l, --lines                 print the newline counts.
    -L, --max-line-length       print the maximum display width.
    -w, --words                 print the word counts.
    -h, --help                  display this help and exit.

EXIT STATUS:
    The wc utility exits with 0 on success, or elsewise if an error occurs.
)";
}

static auto usage_err(std::ostream& os, std::string_view argv0) -> void 
{
    os << "The syntax of the command is incorrect.\nTry "
          << argv0 << " -h for more information.\n";
}

static auto read_err(std::ostream& os, const std::string_view& file) -> void 
{
    os << std::format(
        "error: failed to process '{}': {}\n", file,
        std::error_code {errno, std::generic_category()}.message());
}

static auto chkd_add(std::uintmax_t& res, std::uintmax_t a, std::uintmax_t b)
    -> bool 
{
    if (a + b < a) {
        return false;
    }

    res = a + b;
    return true;
}

static auto write_counts(std::ostream& os, 
                         const options& opts,
                         const fstats& stats, 
                         const char* file) -> void 
{
    // TODO: Format these dynamically like wc does.
    if (opts.lflag) {
        os << std::format("  {:>}", stats.lines);
    }

    if (opts.wflag) {
        os << std::format("  {:>7}", stats.words);
    }

    if (opts.cflag) {
        os << std::format("  {:>7}", stats.bytes);
    }

    if (opts.Lflag) {
        os << std::format("  {:>7}", stats.max_line_length);
    }

    if (file) {
        os << std::format("  {:>7}", file);
    }
    
    /* Ensure lines are written atomically and immediately so that processes 
     * running in parallel do not intersperse their output. */
    os << '\n' << std::flush;
}

[[nodiscard]] static auto parse_options(int argc, char* argv[])
    -> std::expected<options, parse_options_error> 
{
    auto opts {options {}};

    static constexpr const ::option long_options[] {
        {"bytes", no_argument, nullptr, 'c'},
        {"lines", no_argument, nullptr, 'l'},
        {"max-line-length", no_argument, nullptr, 'L'},
        {"words", no_argument, nullptr, 'w'},
        {"help", no_argument, nullptr, 'h'},
        {nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0}};

    while (true) {
        const int c {::getopt_long(argc, argv, "clLwh", long_options, nullptr)};

        if (c == -1) {
            break;
        }

        switch (c) {
        case 'c':
            opts.cflag = true;
            break;

        case 'l':
            opts.lflag = true;
            break;

        case 'L':
            opts.Lflag = true;
            break;

        case 'w':
            opts.wflag = true;
            break;

        case 'h':
            return std::unexpected {parse_options_error::help_requested};

            /* case '?' */
        default:
            return std::unexpected {parse_options_error::unknown_option};
        }
    }
    return opts;
}

[[nodiscard]] static auto wc(const options& opts, std::ifstream& is)
    -> std::expected<fstats, bool> 
{
    auto stats {fstats {}};
    constexpr std::size_t bufsize {262144};
    char buf[bufsize];
    [[maybe_unused]] bool in_word {false};

    std::uintmax_t line_pos {0};
    constexpr std::size_t tab_width {8};

#if 0
    /* TODO: Can we get a file descriptor from ifstream to call posix_fadvise()
     * with POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL? */

    /* TODO: When counting only bytes, save some line- and word-counting overhead
     * by using stat()/fstat()/std::fileystem::file_size. 
     * How to get a file descriptor/path name from an ifstream? */
    if (opts.cflag and not opts.wflag and not opts.lflag and not opts.Lflag) {
        wc_bytes();
    }

    /* TODO: Use a separate loop when counting only lines, or lines and bytes,
     * but not chars or words. */
    else if (not opts.Lflag and not opts.wflag) {
        wc_lines();
    } else {
        // Do the below
    }
#endif
    while (is) {
        is.read(buf, bufsize);

        const auto count {static_cast<std::size_t>(is.gcount())};

        if (count == 0) {
            break;
        }

        stats.bytes += count;

        if (opts.lflag or opts.Lflag or opts.wflag) {
            for (std::size_t i {0}; i < count; ++i) {
                const auto c {static_cast<unsigned char>(buf[i])};

                switch (c) {
                case '\n':
                    ++stats.lines;
                    [[fallthrough]];

                case '\r':
                case '\f':
                    stats.max_line_length =
                        std::max(line_pos, stats.max_line_length);
                    line_pos = 0;
                    in_word = false;
                    break;

                case '\t':
                    line_pos += tab_width - (line_pos % tab_width);
                    in_word = false;
                    break;

                case ' ':
                    ++line_pos;
                    [[fallthrough]];

                case '\v':
                    in_word = false;
                    break;

                default:
                    line_pos += isprint(c) != 0;
                    const bool in_word2 = !isspace(c);
                    stats.words += !in_word & in_word2;
                    in_word = in_word2;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    stats.max_line_length = std::max(line_pos, stats.max_line_length);

    if (is.bad()) {
        return std::unexpected {false};
    }
    return stats;
}

[[nodiscard]] static auto wc_file(const options& opts,
                                  std::ifstream& is, 
                                  const char* file,
                                  int nfiles, 
                                  fstats& total_stats) -> int 
{
    auto const stats {wc(opts, is)};

    if (not stats) {
        read_err(std::cerr, file);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS; /* We only want to exit on overflow. */
    }

    write_counts(std::cout, opts, stats.value(), file);

    if (nfiles > 1) {
        total_stats.max_line_length = std::max(stats.value().max_line_length,
                                               total_stats.max_line_length);

        if (!chkd_add(total_stats.lines, total_stats.lines, stats.value().lines)) {
            std::cerr << "Error: integer overflow in total lines.\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else if (!chkd_add(total_stats.words, total_stats.words, stats.value().words)) {
            std::cerr << "Error: integer overflow in total words.\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else if (!chkd_add(total_stats.bytes, total_stats.bytes, stats.value().bytes)) {
            std::cerr << "Error: integer overflow in total bytes.\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

[[nodiscard]] static auto wc_file(const options& opts,
                                  std::ifstream& is, 
                                  const char* file) -> int 
{
    auto const stats {wc(opts, is)};

    if (not stats) {
        read_err(std::cerr, file);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    write_counts(std::cout, opts, stats.value(), nullptr);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

auto main(int argc, char* argv[]) -> int 
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));

    auto opts {parse_options(argc, argv)};

    if (not opts) {
        if (opts.error() == parse_options_error::help_requested) {
            help(std::cout);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }

        if (opts.error() == parse_options_error::unknown_option) {
            usage_err(std::cerr, argv[0]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    if (not(opts.value().lflag || opts.value().wflag || opts.value().cflag ||
            opts.value().Lflag)) {
        opts.value().lflag = opts.value().wflag = opts.value().cflag = true;
    }

    if (optind == argc) {
        return wc_file(opts.value(), static_cast<std::ifstream&>(std::cin), "stdin");
    }

    auto total_stats {fstats {}};
    int nfiles {optind < argc ? argc - optind : 1};

    for (int i {optind}; i < argc; ++i) {
        if (fs::is_directory(fs::path(argv[i]))) {
            std::cerr << std::format("wc: {}: Is a directory.\n", argv[i]);
            write_counts(std::cout, opts.value(), fstats {0}, argv[i]);
        } else if (std::strcmp(argv[i], "-") == 0 || fs::is_regular_file(fs::path(argv[i]))) {
            if (std::strcmp(argv[i], "-") == 0) {
                if (wc_file(opts.value(), static_cast<std::ifstream&>(std::cin),
                            argv[i], nfiles, total_stats) == EXIT_FAILURE) {
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
            } else {
                auto file {std::ifstream {argv[i], std::ios::binary}};

                if (wc_file(opts.value(), file, argv[i], nfiles, total_stats) ==
                    EXIT_FAILURE) {
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (nfiles > 1) {
        write_counts(std::cout, opts.value(), total_stats, "total");
    }
}

The buffer size is 256K because that is what GNU's implementation uses too (according to a recent commit, they found some speed improvements).
This is the third time I am using C++ for something, so judge accordingly. The TODOs in the code are present because I do not yet know how to solve what they state. The code is complete as it is.
Valgrind reports nothing awry.
Makefile:
CXX = g++-13

CXXFLAGS += -std=c++23
CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
CXXFLAGS += -Wall
CXXFLAGS += -Wfatal-errors
CXXFLAGS += -Wextra
CXXFLAGS += -Wwrite-strings
CXXFLAGS += -Wundef
CXXFLAGS += -Wredundant-decls
CXXFLAGS += -Wdisabled-optimization
CXXFLAGS += -Wdouble-promotion
CXXFLAGS += -Wno-parentheses
CXXFLAGS += -Wpedantic
CXXFLAGS += -pedantic-errors
CXXFLAGS += -Warray-bounds
CXXFLAGS += -Wconversion
CXXFLAGS += -Wsign-conversion
CXXFLAGS += -Wstrict-overflow=2
CXXFLAGS += -Wformat=2
CXXFLAGS += -Wcast-qual
CXXFLAGS += -Wno-unused-function
CXXFLAGS += -Weffc++
CXXFLAGS += -Wuseless-cast

CXXFLAGS += -fsanitize=leak
CXXFLAGS += -fsanitize=undefined

RM = /bin/rm 

TARGET = wc

all: $(TARGET)

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)

.PHONY: all clean
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:

Review Request:
Optimization possibilities, style, bad practices, et cetera.
What modern features can I use to simplify the code cut down on the LOC?

I'm not going to answer because there is already a very good answer, however, this code will not compile on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2022. The getopt functions are POSIX specific and do not port. I did do a portable version a while back. Your version is much simpler than mine.

@pacmaninbw Yes, but with MinGW, they can be compiled on Windows too.  If that's not possible, one can always get the source code for getopt functions (their GNU implementation is distributed under GNU General Public License albeit). If that's not possible, Microsoft also provides a implementation inside the open-source Iotivity software framework (is is distributed under Apache 2.0 License albeit). If that's not possible, one can rewrite them (they're rather simpler). (I did find your question whilst researching for implementations here.)

Does it take into account the different locales? (C, utf-8, utf-16, and many many other possibilities) ?

@OlivierDulac I believe not, no.

When you are reading input from std::cin you can improve performance by unsyncing the C++ streams with C streams: ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); Also since you are not acting interactively you can decouple the std::cin and std::cout with std::cin.tie(nullptr);

It kinda does take locale into account, though. That’s what you’re doing with std::locale::global(std::locale(""));. You don’t use it, though. If you change the format strings for the numbers in write_counts() to "{:>L}" (that is, add “L”), then ./wc wc.cpp on my machine (which is en_CA.utf8) produces “  374    1,154   10,857   wc.cpp”, and LANG=fr_CA.utf8 ./wc wc.cpp produces “  374    1 154   10 857   wc.cpp”. (LANG= ./wc wc.cpp, using the C/POSIX locale, produces “  374     1154    10857   wc.cpp”.)

I won’t do a full review, but I will point out that in wc() is the classic IOStreams anti-pattern of while (is) { is.read(...);. The correct pattern is while (is.read(...)) {. Generally, whenever doing an IOStreams operation, the pattern is if (/*operation*/) ... or while (/*operation*/) ..., because that checks the state of the stream and the results of the operation, whereas if (/*stream is good*/) { /*operation*/ only does the former. Doing while (is) { if (is.read(...)) ... is redundant; if the stream was bad, there can be no read, so it will just return immediately.

Also, to answer the questions in the code: As of C++26, you can use .native_handle() to get a file descriptor from a file stream (but obviously not from a generic stream). But AFAIK, there is no POSIX way to get a file’s path from a file descriptor, nor would it even make sense. I think there are ways do it in practice, but they couldn’t possibly reliably return the same path you opened a file with. If you want that, you’d have to cache it.

The code looks very nice; it's consistent, nicely organized, and global variables have been avoided. There are some minor things that could be improved though:
Naming things
Avoid unnecessary abbreviations. Instead of having cflag and a comment saying it is a "byte count flag", why not name it byte_count_flag, or perhaps just count_bytes? The same goes for the other flags.
Similarly, fstats: just name it file_statistics.
Some abbreviations are fine, as long as it's idiomatic or very localized, and as long as you are consistent. So os for the output stream, a and b for two operands to an operation, optind for the option index, and so on.
However, opts is bad. It should be named options, although that does shadow the type named options. The way this is typically avoided is by using a different naming scheme for types, like using PascalCase. Maybe another name could be chosen for either the type or the local variable, but having one be an abbreviation is not the right solution.
As an exercise, go through all type, function and variable names, think about whether they are an abbreviation or not (sometimes we are so used to it as programmers that we don't even realize we are doing this), and if so, change it to something unabbreviated.
Avoid unnecessary repetition
Instead of:
if (not(opts.value().lflag || opts.value().wflag || opts.value().cflag ||
        opts.value().Lflag)) {
    opts.value().lflag = opts.value().wflag = opts.value().cflag = true;
}

You can avoid repeating value() by writing:
if (not(opts->lflag || opts->wflag || opts->cflag || opts->Lflag)) {
    opts->lflag = opts->wflag = opts->cflag = true;
}

This is less typing and easier to read. Another alternative would be to create a reference to opts.value() and use that.
Pass references to std::istreams instead of std::ifstreams
Some functions take a reference to a std::ifstream as input when they only need a std::istream. Change that, and you also won't need to static_cast<>(std::cin) anymore.
Use argv0 in the help text
Use argv0 instead of hardcoding "wc" as the program name in the usage section of the help text.
Performance
Your code is performing very well, just 50% slower than coreutils' wc utility, which probably is highly optimized. Unless performance is your main goal, I would not sacrifice the simplicity of your code for it.

The coreutils wc utility is written in C rather than C++ or at least it was 16 months ago. Did you compile this -O3 to test it against the coreutils wc utility?

I did indeed compile it with -O3 when comparing. I used perf stat to look at how many CPU cycles it took compared to wc.

To add more performance statictics, its twice as slower than GNU wc when the input is read from a file and one third slower when it's read from a pipe on my computer (Ubuntu 24.04, AMD Ryzen 7 5800h).

    if (fs::is_directory(fs::path(argv[i]))) {
        std::cerr << std::format("wc: {}: Is a directory.\n", argv[i]);
        write_counts(std::cout, opts.value(), fstats {0}, argv[i]);
    } else if (std::strcmp(argv[i], "-") == 0 || fs::is_regular_file(fs::path(argv[i]))) {
        if (std::strcmp(argv[i], "-") == 0) {
            if (wc_file(opts.value(), static_cast<std::ifstream&>(std::cin),
                        argv[i], nfiles, total_stats) == EXIT_FAILURE) {
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        } else {
            auto file {std::ifstream {argv[i], std::ios::binary}};
            if (wc_file(opts.value(), file, argv[i], nfiles, total_stats) == EXIT_FAILURE) {
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
    }
}

Not sure this logic is quite correct. If we supply a file name that doesn't exist, it gets ignored with no error.
Unless I'm missing something it's also more complicated than necessary - I think we could flatten it like so:
auto const path = std::string_view{ argv[i] };

if (fs::is_regular_file(path)) {
    // ...
} else if (fs::is_directory(path)) {
    // ...
} else if (path == "-") {
    // ...
} else {
    // ... oopsy! ... (wc prints "wc: argh: No such file or directory" and then zeros, as for directories)
}

Note that we don't need to use strcmp either.

Good catch! But wc (GNU coreutils) 8.32 does print the error message for me, but not the zeroes. What implementation are you using?

version 8.30. But you're right. When given a single argument, it actually doesn't print zeroes. With multiple arguments (e.g. wc dirthatexists filethatdoesntexist it prints both the error messages and the zeroes.
